# Работа цикла по объекту в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Почему в itemsMap[product.id_product] присваивается только поле id_product, если мы присваиваем целый объект из цикла?

```
itemsMap: function(){
            let state = getProducts();
            let itemsMap = {};

            for(let i = 0; i < state.items.length; i++){
                let product = state.items[i];
                itemsMap[product.id_product] = product;
                console.log(product.id_product);
            }

            return itemsMap;
        }
function getProducts(){
    return [
        {
            id_product: 10,
            title: 'Iphone 5',
            price: 20000
        },
        {
            id_product: 20,
            title: 'Iphone 6',
            price: 25000
        },
        {
            id_product: 30,
            title: 'Iphone 7',
            price: 30000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `console.log(itemsMap[product.id_product]);`

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что _присваивается только поле id_product_?

Comment: @Grundy потому что он выводит в консоль `product.id_product`

Comment: Вот что выводится в консоли

Comment: В консоли выводятся значения полей id_product

Comment: У коде в вопросе ты сам выводишь только одно поле `console.log(product.id_product);` причем даже не из `itemsMap`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var itemsMap = function() {
  let state = getProducts();
  let itemsMap = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    let product = state[i];
    itemsMap[product.id_product] = product;
    console.log(itemsMap[product.id_product]);
  }

  return itemsMap;
}

function getProducts() {
  return [{
      id_product: 10,
      title: 'Iphone 5',
      price: 20000
    },
    {
      id_product: 20,
      title: 'Iphone 6',
      price: 25000
    },
    {
      id_product: 30,
      title: 'Iphone 7',
      price: 30000
    }
  ]
}

itemsMap();
```

Comment: Не понял вашего ответа? Вы просто закомментировали вывод лога

Comment: @AexFun нет, я продемонстрировал, что функция возращает результат, у которого значения свойств - полные объекты из массива